# Read Json from url without download

Tags: c#, json, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to read Json string from URL, but when I using Chrome web page will show this string:

[image]

And when I using C# WebBrowser it ask me download file to read
I try to use WebClient DownloadString but this site use cookie from login page and it show arlert "Request Invaild":

[image]

Please help me, I'm sorry if my English is not good

**Update:** Here is my code:

```
wbTest.Navigate("http://authen.dzogame.com:8080/LauncherLogin.aspx?gid=200");
wbTest.Document.GetElementById("tbxUserName").SetAttribute("value", "7honda");
wbTest.Document.GetElementById("tbxPassword").SetAttribute("value", "111111");
wbTest.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin").InvokeMember("click");
```

**Update 2:** I try to get/set cookie, but it's not working.

```
wb.Navigate("http://authen.dzogame.com:8080/LauncherLogin.aspx?gid=200");
Wait();
id = txtID.Text;
pass = txtPassword.Text;
wb.Document.GetElementById("tbxUserName").SetAttribute("value", id);
wb.Document.GetElementById("tbxPassword").SetAttribute("value", pass);
wb.Document.GetElementById("btnLogin").InvokeMember("Click");
Wait();
string cookie = wb.Document.Cookie;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
string token = wc.DownloadString("http://authen.dzogame.com:8080/ReturnLogin.ashx");
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information, such as the code that you have written so far etc?

Comment: Consider `WebClient` or `HttpRequest`?

Comment: @Thematkinson I updated my code.

Comment: @LeiYang this site using cookie to show json string, http://authen.dzogame.com:8080/ReturnLogin.ashx just show after log in, and if I login at Webbrowser and get json string at WebClient it will be "Request Invaild"

Comment: cookies can be programmly set in `WebClient` or `HttpRequest`

Comment: @LeiYang ^^ thank you, I will try to search it. Your meaning : get cookies from Webbrowser and set in WebClient or HttpRequest, is it right?

Comment: yes this is very common ways. you can often press F12 in Chrome or use Fiddler to see post/get details

Comment: @LeiYang yes, thank you very much. I will try it ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to send the query with cookies from your browser control but the property cookie doesn't contain httpOnly cookie => so you you don't have the session cookie.

Getting the httpOnly is a little bit triky.

1. Add this code to your class so you can get the httpOnly cookie.

   ```
   [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(
   string url,
   string cookieName,
   StringBuilder cookieData,
   ref int size,
   Int32 dwFlags,
   IntPtr lpReserved);

   private const Int32 InternetCookieHttponly = 0x2000;

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets the URI cookie container.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="uri">The URI.</param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public static string GetUriCookieContainer(Uri uri)
   {
       // Determine the size of the cookie
       int datasize = 8192 * 16;
       StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
       if (!InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), null, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero))
       {
           if (datasize < 0)
               return null;
           // Allocate stringbuilder large enough to hold the cookie
           cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
           if (!InternetGetCookieEx(
               uri.ToString(),
               null, cookieData,
               ref datasize,
               InternetCookieHttponly,
               IntPtr.Zero))
               return null;
       }
       return cookieData.ToString();
   }
   ```
2. You can get the json like with the code below

   ```
   private void func()
   {
       // your code for login here ....




       var urlJson = new Uri("http://authen.dzogame.com:8080/LauncherLogin.aspx?gid=200");

       var cookie = GetUriCookieContainer(urlJson);

       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://authen.dzogame.com:8080/ReturnLogin.ashx");
       request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
       request.Accept = "*/*";
       string jsonResponse = null;
       using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
       {
           using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
           {
               jsonResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this open source JSON Framework : http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"status\":\"1\"...");
```

Comment: I read it, but I wanna read Json string without file download.