# Unable to get GoogleTrends Data using C#

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse, google-trends

referring to this [C# get html from url. Error (429) unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044660/c-sharp-get-html-from-url-error-429-unknown)  I am also getting the same issue. Can anyone please help. I am using GoogleTrends nuget package in C#. but unfortunately they doesn't have enough examples or explanation to use this.

Comment: Error 429 explicitly states that there were too many request from the same app to the server, so this app was blocked. The answer you reference suggests using a C# API. In order to avoid paying too much for using an API, you could use web scrappers, but they will also be blocked by IP eventually.

Comment: if i am using webbrowser or selenium it gives data but using httprequest or webclient  it says directly (429) unknown.

Comment: Have you tried to pretend that you're a browser by specifying `User Agent`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51639210/437393

Comment: Recommended way of doing it in C# is `IHttpClient` rather than obsolete `WebClient` https://stackoverflow.com/a/50057689/437393

Comment: this is working now. i have used httprequest with random cookies.  and 429 error gone. the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643808/read-json-from-url-without-download helped me in this